# Zooming functionality in OpenCV imshow in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

In Ubuntu, OpenCV's imshow function has a window where different options such as zoom in, zoom out, pan window, etc, are available by python, like this:

[image]

Why doesn't that exist in the C + + version？

Comment: it does. your build of opencv simply wasn't built with the Qt library.

Answer (score 0):

You need Qt GUI. You can check this [solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5261648/Problem-in-setting-up-QT-to-integrate-with-opencv).

Comment: Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.